# How do I upgrade WordPress Installed by APT?

Tags: apt, upgrade, apache2, wordpress

I installed WordPress from the console of Ubuntu 20.10 on a local machine and after setting up a site and attempting to install some plugins, I saw a notice that some, including Jetpack, were not compatible with my version of WordPress. The installed version is 5.3.5 and the current version as of today is 5.5.2 (when my hosted sites auto-updated and sent email notices).

My news installation's dashboard says "You have the latest version of WordPress. Future security updates will be applied automatically. If you need to re-install version –, you can do so here:" The "Check for Updates" button returns a message that I have the latest version but we know that's not so and the check doesn't even get my version info but inserts a dash (–) instead.

**How can I access a repository with the current WP version so that I can upgrade without having to download and install from the archive at wordpress.org?** The apt installation uses an array of directories and offers the convenience of running more than one site from the single codebase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To update software that was installed in `apt`, you use the following two commands:

```
sudo apt update
```

*(to update the list of available software)*

and

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

*(to update packages to the latest version)*

---

If you are wondering why Ubuntu repositories don't have the latest software version available somewhere else, please see "[Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)".

Comment: I had already done apt upgrade specifically for WordPress and it said I had the latest version. I'm wondering if there's not a repository that has the latest version that I can add to the list of packages.

Comment: *"I'm wondering if there's not a repository"* -- `wordpress` is in [Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wordpress&searchon=names&suite=groovy&section=all).  WordPress documentation would tell you if there are other official ways to install the software.  As far as I know there are not any official PPAs for WordPress, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: See: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/

Comment: Hopefully someone with a Ubuntu answer will reply. I already said I don't want to download WordPress files and am looking for a repository that stores the updates as I want to proceed using apt/apt-get. All I want is follow up on this https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview. It'd be good to know whether installing by this method means you can't update using the WP dashboard and that it means staying at the installed version for an unspecified time until or unless it's a security fix from the repo.

Comment: My answer explains the process to update software with apt. This is the "Ubuntu answer". If you read the link in my answer, this might explain why the "Ubuntu answer" is not working for you. Wordpress handles its own updates and you should not have to download any files manually. But the fact that you've been doing this anyway may have broken your ability to update automatically or guided. Your link has to do with *installation* and nothing to do with *updates*.  If you need help understanding this process, I suggest that you read and follow the WP documentation. There is not a WordPress PPA.

Answer (score 0):

You could upgrade your server to 21.04.  It looks like the repo there has a more recent version of Wordpress.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wordpress

Answer (score 0):

"How do I upgrade WordPress Installed by APT".

There is two main ways to do it.

1. Use the apt command as described in other answers.
2. Install the software from "source". And the gist of this method is to:

- Make a backup of the configuration
- Uninstall the apt package
- Make a installation from source, and this is well described at https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/
- Restore backup if its compatible with previous version